# Is there a way to set css in harp when displaying markdown files?

Tags: markdown, harp

Markdown without css is not very appealing to look at, and I would like to customize the visual display when viewing markdown files in harp. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `_layout.ejs` or `.jade` file in your project, it can wrap all the Markdown you write.

For example, in `_layout.ejs` you might have:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <script src="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, any Markdown files you have will be rendered where `<%- yield %>` is, so you can style them in the `main.css` file I’ve referenced in the link tag there.

[Here is the full documentation for layout files](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/layout)

I also go through this in more depth in an article about [starting a blog with Harp](http://kennethormandy.com/journal/start-a-blog-with-harp). Hope it’s helpful!

Comment: Thanks! This is great!